# How to respond to prompt in shell script with loop variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a cli command to delete an entity like  `admin delete <<entity>>`.

Now, my usecase is to delete a bunch of entities with entity names in a file. I can just iterate over the file and delete these entities like :

```
cat file.txt | while read entity 
do
   admin delete $entity
done
```

The catch is that the `admin delete <<entity>>` command asks for a confirmation of the name of the entity before deleting the entity like `To proceed, type the full name of the entity again here`.

How do I feed in the loop variable as the response to this prompt during the shell script execution for each entity ?

Comment: Depends on how this `admin` command is written. Does it prompt stdin or the TTY? Does it still prompt if it _doesn't have_ any TTY available at all?

Comment: Also, in general, `cat file.txt | while read` [causes bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). Use `while read entity; do ... done <file.txt` instead, or in this case, `while read entity <&3; do ... 3<file.txt` so your input is on a file descriptor that you don't need to worry about `admin` reading from.

Comment: _Typically_, a well-written tool that follows UNIX conventions will only prompt for confirmation if its stdin is attached to a TTY; so `admin delete "$entity" </dev/null` may suppress the prompt altogether. And if it doesn't, it would be very reasonable to file a bug report asking the people who write the tool to make it do so in the future; confirmation prompts are there for human users -- presenting them to scripts is just making work for people with no good purpose.

Comment: ...however, if you have something that _isn't_ a well-written tool, and also is ignoring stdin to be deliberately hard to feed from a script, that's the kind of case that `expect` and newer derivative tools (`pexpect`, etc) is written for.

Answer (score 0):

A simple go-around is using a **`here document`**.

```sh
admin delete $entity <<< $entity
```

For comparision:

```sh
fn() { local x && read x; [ "$x" = "$1" ] && echo yep || echo nope; }
```

run as

```
var=smthg
foo=smthg
fn $var <<< $foo
```